# How to use variable inside a class in the public function??Maybe reference?

Tags: php, reference

```
<?php class pac{
public $q=5;

public function yo($q){
$v=$q+2;
print $v;

}

}

$a=new pac;
$a->yo($q);
?>
```

Hi guys ,i am beginner,sorry for stupid questions!

So the question is xD : how to use $q?? I need to put reference on it ??

Comment: did you try `$this->q`?

Comment: yea,i tried,great ,thats what i wanted.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use `$q` but `$q` isn't defined. If you want to use the object variable `$q` you can use `$a->q`.

```
<?php 
    class pac{
        public $q=5;

        public function yo($q){
            $v=$q+2;
            print $v;
        }
    }
    $a=new pac;
    $a->yo($a->q);
?>
```

Another option is to use the object variable in your method instead of pass it as parameter:

```
<?php 
    class pac{
        public $q=5;

        public function yo(){
            $v=$this->q+2;
            print $v;
        }
    }
    $a=new pac;
    $a->yo();
?>
```